# PostgreSQL copy to a new table with one extra column. How?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-triggers

I am trying to make a forum database and in this database I have a trigger. After the Insert it should copy the values of the other table into the new one, but should also make a new column showing the actual registerdate of the user. 
Here is the trigger code:

```
Create OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertUser() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $insertUser$

BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO public.freshlyinserted(user_id, username, bday, gender, uemail, pasword)
    VALUES (NEW.user_id, NEW.username, NEW.bday, NEW.gender, NEW.uemail, NEW.pasword, NEW.registerdate);

RETURN NEW;
END;
$insertUser$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER moveUserToInserted
AFTER INSERT ON forumusers
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertUser();
```

When i try this, it tells me this:

> ERROR Record "new" has no field "registerdate" CONTEXT: SQL statement
>   "INSERT INTO public.freshlyinserted(user_id, username, bday, gender,
>   uemail, pasword)  VALUES (NEW.user_id, NEW.username, NEW.bday,
>   NEW.gender, NEW.uemail, NEW.pasword, NEW.registerdate)". PL/pgSQL
>   function insertuser() row 2 for SQL statement

The forumuser table doesn't have the "registerdate" column...but I really would like it for the new Table withe the actual date(i dont know how to do it tho). I would be happy, if I get help with this. I will post any more needed code!
Btw. Without the registerdate, it works...but then the table would make no sense for me XD

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **current_date** like this:

```
Create OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertUser() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $insertUser$

BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO public.freshlyinserted(user_id, username, bday, gender, uemail, pasword)
    VALUES (NEW.user_id, NEW.username, NEW.bday, NEW.gender, NEW.uemail, NEW.pasword, current_date);

RETURN NEW;
END;
$insertUser$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER moveUserToInserted
AFTER INSERT ON forumusers
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertUser();
```

You can also use **current_timestamp**

Here you can see what will they return or save when you use them: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=57bae2ba351bac477724aa5551c73ee2

Comment: thank you so much! Now it works :) I also figured out i forgot to put registerdate in the freshlyinserted table in INSERT INTO... XD 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just replace NEW.registerdate with the current date for which you can use the function NOW()

Comment: So you mean just like this: VALUES (NEW.user_id, NEW.username, NEW.bday, NEW.gender, NEW.uemail, NEW.pasword, GETDATE());

This is not working thi; i get an error again :
ERROR: Function getdate() does not exist

Maybe I am just stupid XD

Comment: I edited my answer after I posted it but guess you read it too soon. You are using postgres, so GETDATE() doesn't exist, but you can use NOW() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't need to change the trigger, you can use **DEFAULT** clause while creating/altering a table.

```
ALTER TABLE public.freshlyinserted
    ALTER COLUMN registerdate
        SET DEFAULT now();
```